# Passing field info as parameter to function in report

Tags: report, ms-access-2010

I'm new to access 2010 and having some difficulty with a report.  Here's the report I'm working on:

[image]

This is a time sheet report that displays shift dates for each employee.  I created a dummy function in Module1 which will require me to pass an employeeID from each record as a parameter.  For testing purposes the function is as follows:

```
Public Function GetTotalHours(EmployeeIdentifier As String) As String
GetTotalHours = "666"
End Function
```

The report uses a query that does obtain the employeeID for every record and I thought I could just refer to it just as you see in the image.  However, when I run the report, I get prompted for the employeeID.  That's not what I wanted.  I just wanted the report to automatically capture the employeeID from each record and pass it to the function.  How am I supposed to do this properly?

Comment: Please add the full SQL of your report's RecordSource to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your query doesn't retrieve employeeID. Add this field to SQL and then you will be able to use your function:
`GetTotalHours([employeeID])`
where `[employeeID]` is name of field from base query or name of control with ID data on form/report. Control is not mandatory in this case.